# Custom button on custom taxonomy listing page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hooks, buttons

I want to have a custom button at custom taxonomy listing page. Please see the screenshot, I need a button so that I can export all my terms.

[image]

I am not able to find any hook to do something like that. Hook I have tried is `admin_footer,` but it's used for any javascript type of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This action hook (found in `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php`) will output the button *below* the table (not *quite* where you have asked to position it, but it is an easily available action and outside the `form` table.)

```
$taxonomy = 'location'; // you will probably need to change this
add_action('after-{$taxonomy}-table','custom_export_button');

function custom_export_button($taxonomy) {
    $export_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php').'?action=export_taxonomy';
    echo "<form action='".$export_url."' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='taxonomy' value='".$taxonomy."'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='EXPORT'></form>";
}

add_action('wp_ajax_export_taxonomy','custom_export_taxonomy');
function custom_export_taxonomy() {
    // YOUR CUSTOM TAXONOMY EXPORT FUNCTION
}
```

Comment: thanks for this :) is there any hook to bring that button before list of categories. I tried "before-{taxonomy}-table" but not working, tried google no results. is there any hook to do that. ??

Comment: no there isn't unfortunately, it doesn't exist in edit-tags.php... hence I picked that one... you can try: `{$taxonomy}_pre_add_form` but it will end up top left I think... perhaps better to use the after-table one and wrap your form and button in a `<div style="position:absolute; top:50px;">` to bring it up to the top, but this seems a bit hacky. on that front you could insert your form/button in the right place with jQuery.

Comment: can you please help me in hook before or after custom post table like we used these 'after-{$taxonomy}-table' and {$taxonomy}_pre_add_form

Comment: unfortunately there does not seem to be any hooks at tall like this in `edit.php`... you might have to use something like `add_action('all_admin_notices','custom_function',999);` and within your hooked function check that the current page is `edit.php` and the post type is your custom one before outputting.

Comment: its not possible :( there must be something I am damn sure wordpress cant skip this. I will keep finding it, till then I am using your suggested hook. can you please tell me how to check current page is edit.php ? using URL ?

Comment: wordpress sets a global for this you can try `global $pagenow; if ($pagenow != 'edit.php') {return;}`... the only other thing I can think of here is you can probably add your own custom column you could search for an example for that.